# C++/CLI: Cannot convert parameter

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, c++-cli

I have a small issue and I will explain it first. I am trying to convert a C# code which works with a C# dll into C++ using C++/CLI, so my C++ application can work with the C# dll. Following is a part of the C# code

```
private void USB_OnSpecifiedDeviceRemoved(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.DevicePresent = false;
        }

this.USB.OnSpecifiedDeviceRemoved += new EventHandler(this.USB_OnSpecifiedDeviceRemoved);
```

Following is my C++ conversion

```
   usb.OnSpecifiedDeviceRemoved +=  System::EventHandler(this->USB_OnSpecifiedDeviceRemoved(nullptr,nullptr));


    void MissileLauncher::USB_OnSpecifiedDeviceRemoved(System::Object sender, System::EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

When I run my C++ code, I get the following error

```
   1>------ Build started: Project: CallToCSharp, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  MissileLauncher.cpp
1>MissileLauncher.cpp(109): error C2664: 'MissileLauncher::USB_OnSpecifiedDeviceRemoved' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'nullptr' to 'System::Object'
1>          No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called
1>MissileLauncher.cpp(109): fatal error C1903: unable to recover from previous error(s); stopping compilation
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Why this is happening? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two issues with your conversion. Firstly you are incorrectly adding the event handler to the event. It should be something like the following:

```
usb.OnSpecifiedDeviceRemoved +=
    gcnew System::EventHandler(this,
        &MissileLauncher::USB_OnSpecifiedDeviceRemoved);
```

Secondly, the signature of the event handler is incorrect. You need to use tracking references for the arguments, which are denoted using `^`:

```
void MissileLauncher::USB_OnSpecifiedDeviceRemoved(System::Object ^sender,
                                                   System::EventArgs ^e)
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: What kind of great help is this! Awesome!